# HOw to learn Ubuntu 17.04 desktop version?

Tags: software-installation, updates

I am very new to linux and have downloaded ubuntu 17.04 on my 32 bit machine with 500GB hard disk.

I am getting problems in understanding and fed up with daily errors and bug reports please help. I have space management issues and many more.It would be beneficial if I get a single source to learn.
Thanks!

Comment: If you have specific issues, please post separate questions for each issue, explaining what the problem is and what you have tried so far to solve it.

Comment: trick 1 - when searching on error messages do your searching in Google not in search field of this forum ... google does a better job ...

trick 2 - simplify the wording of your search questions, if no answers appear use fewer words, search for concept not specifics ...

Comment: trick 3 - perform your ubuntu changes on a box which can be reformatted and started with a fresh ubuntu install , sometimes learning the hard way will break the box, once you have a toy machine to destroy at will you are more free to issue questionable commands, especially as sudo , this will speed up your learning ...

trick 4 - ask fewer question instead focus research time digging for answers, very often best questions have very nice answers, far more pointed than simply asking a redundant question ...

Welcome Aboard !!!

Comment: Thanx buddy for the tricks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Really the best way to learn is just read plenty of different resources. If you are unsure what you are doing before doing it, look it up first. There's a good chance others have asked the same questions as you in the past.

The Ubuntu wiki is of course a great place to start https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Home

Comment: thanx buddy can you solve out one problem if u r free